# python unittest for argparse

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, argparse

I have a function inside a module that creates an `argparse`:

```
def get_options(prog_version='1.0', prog_usage='', misc_opts=None):
     options = [] if misc_opts is None else misc_opts
     parser = ArgumentParser(usage=prog_usage) if prog_usage else ArgumentParser()
     parser.add_argument('-v', '--version', action='version', version='%(prog)s {}'.format(prog_version))
     parser.add_argument('-c', '--config', dest='config', required=True, help='the path to the configuration file')

    for option in options:
        if 'option' in option and 'destination' in option:
            parser.add_argument(option['option'],
                                dest=option.get('destination', ''),
                                default=option.get('default', ''),
                                help=option.get('description', ''),
                                action=option.get('action', 'store'))

    return parser.parse_args()
```

A sample `myapp.py` would be:

```
my_options = [
    {
        "option": "-s",
        "destination": "remote_host",
        "default": "127.0.0.1",
        "description": "The remote server name or IP address",
        "action": "store"
    },
]

# Get Command Line Options
options = get_options(misc_opts=my_options)
print options.config
print options.remote_host
```

and this will be called as:

```
$> python myapp.py -c config.yaml
$> config.yaml
   127.0.0.1
```

Now, I am trying to create a unit test for this function but my problem is that I can't pass command line parameters via test code.

```
# mytest.py
import unittest
from mymodule import get_options

class argParseTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
     def test_parser(self):
         options = get_options()
         # ...pass the command line arguments...
         self.assertEquals('config.yaml', options.config) # ofcourse this fails because I don't know how I will pass the command line arguments
```

My problem is that I need to pass the command line arguments to `get_options()` but I don't know how to do it properly.

Expected proper call: `python mytest.py` (`-c config.yaml` should be passed inside the test code somehow.)

What is "working"/not working right now:

1. `python mytest.py -c config.yaml` is also not working. Returns `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'config'` since it expects me to call `argParseTestCase` instead. In other words, `python mytest.py -c argParseTestCase` "works" but would ofcourse be an return `AssertionError: 'config.yaml' != 'argParseTestCase'`
2. `python mytest.py -v` to run the unit test in verbose mode also fails. It returns:

   > test_parser (**main**.argParseTestCase) ... mytest.py 1.0 ERROR 
   >   ERROR: test_parser (**main**.argParseTestCase)
   >   Traceback (most recent call last): 
   >   File "tests/unit_tests/mytest.py", line 376, in test_parser options = get_options() 
   >   File "/root/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mymodule.py", line 61, in get_options return parser.parse_args()
   >   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 1701, in parse_args args, argv = self.parse_known_args(args, namespace)
   >   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 1733, in parse_known_args namespace, args = self._parse_known_args(args, namespace)
   >   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 1939, in _parse_known_args start_index = consume_optional(start_index)
   >   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 1879, in consume_optional take_action(action, args, option_string)
   >   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 1807, in take_action action(self, namespace, argument_values, option_string)
   >   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 1022, in **call** parser.exit(message=formatter.format_help())
   >   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 2362, in exit _sys.exit(status) 
   >   SystemExit: 0

Answer (score 6):

I prefer explicitly passing arguments instead of relying on globally available attributes such as `sys.argv` (which `parser.parse_args()` does internally). Thus I usually use `argparse` by passing the list of arguments myself (to `main()` and subsequently `get_options()` and wherever you need them):

```
def get_options(args, prog_version='1.0', prog_usage='', misc_opts=None):
    # ...
    return parser.parse_args(args)
```

and then pass in the arguments

```
def main(args):
    get_options(args)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

that way I can replace and test any list of arguments I like

```
options = get_options(['-c','config.yaml'])
self.assertEquals('config.yaml', options.config)
```

Answer (score 4):

Your error message stack is hard to read because it is in quoted form rather than code.  But I think the `-v` argument is producing a `sys.exit`.  `version` is like `help` - it's supposed to display a message and then exit.  The `-v` is used by `unittest`, but is also read by your parser.

There is an `argparse` unittest module, `test/test_argparse.py`.  You may need a development Python installation to see that.  Some tests are straightforward, others use specialized testing structure.  Some of that special code creates arguments in the same way you do with `options`.

The are two special issues:

- generating the input.  `parse_args` uses `sys.argv[1:]` unless its `argv` parameter is not `None`.  So you can test a parser by either modifying the `sys.argv` list (`unittest` has already used your commandline values), or by passing a `argv=None` keyword argument into your function and on to `parse_args`.  Trying to make a commandline meant for the `unittest` code to work with `get_options` is too complicated.
- trapping the output, especially the `sys.exit` generated by errors.  One option is to subclass `ArgumentParser` and give it a different `error` and/or `exit` method.  Another is to wrap the function call in a `try` block.

`unittest` takes `-c` argument, but with a different syntax and meaning

```
 -c, --catch      Catch control-C and display results
```

and `-v` is `verbose`, not `version`.

=============

This tests the `config` argument (in a self contained one file form)

```
import unittest
import sys
#from mymodule import get_options

def get_options(argv=None, prog_version='1.0', prog_usage='', misc_opts=None):
    # argv is optional test list; uses sys.argv[1:] is not provided
    from argparse import ArgumentParser
    options = [] if misc_opts is None else misc_opts
    parser = ArgumentParser(usage=prog_usage) if prog_usage else ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-v', '--version', action='version', version='%(prog)s {}'.format(prog_version))
    parser.add_argument('-c', '--config', dest='config', help='the path to the configuration file')

    for option in options:
        if 'option' in option and 'destination' in option:
            parser.add_argument(option['option'],
                                dest=option.get('destination', ''),
                                default=option.get('default', ''),
                                help=option.get('description', ''),
                                action=option.get('action', 'store'))

    args = parser.parse_args(argv)
    print('args',args)
    return args

class argParseTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
     def test_config(self):
         sys.argv[1:]=['-c','config.yaml']       
         options = get_options()
         self.assertEquals('config.yaml', options.config) 
     def test_version(self):
         sys.argv[1:]=['-v']   
         with self.assertRaises(SystemExit):
                    get_options() 
         # testing version message requires redirecting stdout
     # similarly for a misc_opts test

if __name__=='__main__':
    unittest.main()
```