# How do you write unittest for the argparse of a python module?

Tags: argparse, python-unittest

I have a Python module that uses the argparse library. 
How do I write tests for that section of the code base?

show_version.py

```
import argparse
def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
    parser.add_argument('-j', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('-e', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('-h', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('-g')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    try:
       ...
    except Exception as e:
        ...
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Because it normally parses `sys.argv`, and sends error messages to `sys.stdout` or `stderr`, and exits, it's a bit tricky.  Plus the `unittest` drivers parses `sys.argv`.  Dev. versions of Python include a `test_argparse.py` unittesting file that may give you ideas.  But it is large and complicated.

Comment: From the `related` sidebar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18160078/how-do-you-write-tests-for-the-argparse-portion-of-a-python-module, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37697502/python-unittest-for-argparse, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42331049/how-to-test-python-classes-that-depend-on-argparse